# Can I make custom function on google spreadsheet without Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-custom-function

I'm using google spreadsheet with Google Apps Script.

but it gives me error message too easily. like this

> Error
>   Script invoked too many times per second for this Google user account. (line 0).

Is there any way to avoid the error? (except the way reduce function call)
or alternative Spreadsheet program that support Javascript function define?

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) you can work around this by ensuring that your function supports ranges, and the function on a range. See also [the section on Optimization](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#optimization) on the Custom Functions in Google Sheets page.

Answer (score 0):

To create a custom function you should use Google Apps Script, it's the only way. Regarding the way to avoid the error, there are several things that could be done but to be certain about what is required in your case you should add more details.